# clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=corei7-avx'

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the following error when installing the `rasa==3.2.8` python package.
I am using a Macbook M1 pro machine.
Error I am getting is: `clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=corei7-avx'`
Since I am using M1 Max processor, why it is picking up corei7-avx?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/l5/7tbnm_3d2f1_hdm70q95lbpc0000gn/T/pip-install-bfyhfasf/blis/setup.py", line 239, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 698, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 346, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/private/var/folders/l5/7tbnm_3d2f1_hdm70q95lbpc0000gn/T/pip-install-bfyhfasf/blis/setup.py", line 103, in build_extensions
          objects = self.compile_objects(compiler.split("-")[0], arch, OBJ_DIR)
        File "/private/var/folders/l5/7tbnm_3d2f1_hdm70q95lbpc0000gn/T/pip-install-bfyhfasf/blis/setup.py", line 188, in compile_objects
          objects.append(self.build_object(env=env, **spec))
        File "/private/var/folders/l5/7tbnm_3d2f1_hdm70q95lbpc0000gn/T/pip-install-bfyhfasf/blis/setup.py", line 201, in build_object
          subprocess.check_call(command, cwd=BLIS_DIR)
        File "/Users/avirajkhare/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['clang', '-c', '/private/var/folders/l5/7tbnm_3d2f1_hdm70q95lbpc0000gn/T/pip-install-bfyhfasf/blis/blis/_src/kernels/sandybridge/3/bli_gemm_sandybridge_asm_d8x4.c', '-o', '/var/folders/l5/7tbnm_3d2f1_hdm70q95lbpc0000gn/T/tmp7n00zegk/bli_gemm_sandybridge_asm_d8x4.o', '-O3', '-mavx', '-mfpmath=sse', '-march=corei7-avx', '-fPIC', '-std=c99', '-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L', '-DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.1"', '-DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY', '-Iinclude/darwin-x86_64', '-I./frame/3/', '-I./frame/ind/ukernels/', '-I./frame/1m/', '-I./frame/1f/', '-I./frame/1/', '-I./frame/include', '-I/private/var/folders/l5/7tbnm_3d2f1_hdm70q95lbpc0000gn/T/pip-install-bfyhfasf/blis/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```